# Part of my Robot gets embedded inside the ground for ROS and Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While Spawning my URDF in ROS and Gazebo half of my Bipedal Robot gets embedded inside the ground. I know it has to do with the way my URDF tree is structured, but I cant figure out a way to tell ROS or Gazebo that my foot link should be in contact with the floor. Please any clue or help would be useful. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225133/part-of-my-robot-gets-embedded-inside-the-ground-for-ros-and-gazebo/) by [ezeob002](https://answers.ros.org/users/25741/ezeob002/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-01-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MahdiehNejati](https://answers.ros.org/users/24953/mahdiehnejati/) on 2016-01-26**:
Can you please provide a link to your URDF?

**Comment by [ezeob002](https://answers.ros.org/users/25741/ezeob002/) on 2016-01-26**:
Here is the link to my urdf file.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j2ijqd6oqb05y4t/AADy4BlK3_OWDStSIivlFaIXa?dl=0

Thanks

**Comment by [ezeob002](https://answers.ros.org/users/25741/ezeob002/) on 2016-01-26**:
I just added it. Thank you

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2016-01-27**:
did you export the model from somewhere?

**Comment by [ezeob002](https://answers.ros.org/users/25741/ezeob002/) on 2016-01-27**:
Nope I made the model using Solidworks, exported the model with simmechanics and made some modifications before trying to spawn in Gazebo and ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Coordinate system origin of your model may not be the bottom-most point. Therefore, if you define it as your base link, it will be snapped to ground. On Solidworks, you can define a coordinate system at the ground level of your model, and while exporting URDF you can select that coordinates as your reference frame.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ezeob002](https://answers.ros.org/users/25741/ezeob002/) on 2016-01-27**:
I have a reference plane in my assembly, how do you set the reference plane as your coordinates reference frame while exporting through simmechanics. Thanks

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2016-01-27**:
Check if the global origin is on the plane that is intersecting the model